# jquery php script to get all the results on page?

Tags: php, jquery, scripting

This is my college result page

http://results.mu.ac.in/choose_nob.php?exam_id=2025&exam_year=2011&exam_month=MAY

I want to get `results of no 9500 to 9600 on one page`.
is it possible to do so using `jquery php`?

if I insert 9500 I get
The result of seat number 9500 is Passed with First Class
Congratulations

so I want it on one page like this

```
seat number 9500 is Passed with First Class
seat number 9501 is Passed with First Class
.....
.......
....  so on
seat number 9600 is Passed with First Class

Note : I don't have access to college website's source code.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `jQuery php`?

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways.

1) gm
first you need something like [greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/)
then write a gm script script, there is plenty exemple [userscripts](http://userscripts.org/)

2) crawler. 
you can use php or other to call "http://results.mu.ac.in/get_resultb.php" with correct parameters, and do what you want with the result.